# Can I programmatically get the root uri of a NiFi flow?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm programmatically creating a NiFi flow using the NiFi api.

I created a process group (I'll call it *PG*) inside the root process group.
Inside the PG I want a Remote Process Group pointing to the root.

The Remote Process Group request-payload requires the **target uri** of the process group it is pointing to (in this case the uri of the root).

Is there a way to get that uri programmatically via the api?

In other words, can I somehow programmatically get the uri of the root?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you just need to set it to the same hostname:port you're sending the RPG request to, except you replace `/nifi-api` and everything that follows with just `/nifi`, that's how you'd do it manually.

Comment: You can have the root uri with the following endpoint: 

/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root/status

Comment: @Pdeuxa Where in the response entity is the uri? I'm receiving back a response with the id, name, statusLastRefreshed, and an aggregateObject object.

Comment: You will have the id of the root process group. As it is still a process group you can form the uri with id, and use the nifi api related to the process group.

Comment: @Pdeuxa How can I form the uri with the id? the uri should be: hostname:port/nifi

Comment: On my program I form the uri with the following `uri= hostname:port + "/nifi-api/process-groups/" +  req.json()["processGroupStatus"]["aggregateSnapshot"]['id']`

But mattyb is right for remote PG, normally they point to the main uri , which is host:port/nifi